# What g++ option prevents inlining lambda-functions if compiled with -Os instead of -O2

Tags: c++, lambda, g++, compiler-optimization, avr-gcc

Here the simple code for compile-time repetition of a lambda. I compiled for AVR with `-Os` and `-O2`. With `-Os` the lambda isn't inlined but with `-O2`. The g++ manual says that `-Os` is same as `-O2` but disables some optimizations which increase the code size. I wonder if I can tweak the g++ options to inline such simple lambdas.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <utility>

volatile uint8_t x;

namespace detail {
    template<auto... II, typename F>
    void repeat_impl(std::index_sequence<II...>, F&& f) {
        ( ((void)II, f()) , ...);
    }
}

template<auto N, typename F>
void repeat(F&& f) {
    detail::repeat_impl(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}, static_cast<F&&>(f));
}

int main() {
    repeat<10>([](){
        x/=2;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These three seem to be related with inline, turned on at -O2 but not -Os:

```
-finline-small-functions 
-findirect-inlining 
-fpartial-inlining
```

You could add one by one to -Os. Although inline may happen in an early phase of compile & optimization, there might be possibility that a function becomes feasible for inline after another optimization preceding inline is applied.

I do not think always_inline attribute is in C++ standard. (not sure, though) If it is not, it depends on the compiler. Gcc seems to support the attribute. Adding the attribute to the function would result in the function inlined.